# How to query all shops around a certain longitude/latitude using osm-postgis?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis

I loaded the map of city Munich (from openstreetMap) into postgis with tool osm2pgsql -s modus

now how could I get all shops around a certain point, say (a,b), within 100 meters,  in a most efficient way

I know it is something like

```
select name, shop
from planet_osm_point
where ST_DWithin(? ,ST_Point(a,b):geometry, 100)
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Not sure if this helps you but note that you don't have to import OSM data for running such queries since there is also [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). You could extract all shops in Munich without the need of any local data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query is already a correct and efficient way to query the data you need.

You only need one adjustments: The function `St_Point` returns a geometry without SRID (by the way, no cast to geometry is needed), but the SRID must be set, to avoid the error:

> ERROR:  Operation on two GEOMETRIES with different SRIDs

Use the postgis function `St_SetSrid` to set the srid:

```
ST_SetSrid(ST_Point(a, b), srid)
```

See also [St_SetSrid](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html)

If you ran osm2pgsql using the default options, the srid should be 900913:

```
SELECT name, shop
FROM planet_osm_point
WHERE ST_DWithin(way ,ST_SetSrid(ST_Point(a, b), 900913), 100);
```

For more infos about srid and spatial references see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRID and [http://spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/)

About SRID 900913: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator

Comment: I am having trouble getting this query to work using (48.137969, 11.573829) for (a, b), and opened a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52180005/retrieve-closest-road-when-given-lat-long-using-osm-in-postgres-with-postgis.