# Retrieve closest road when given (lat, long) using OSM in Postgres with Postgis using SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, gps, openstreetmap, postgis

Given a set (lat, long) I am trying to find the maximum speed using "max_speed" and street type using "highway".

I have loaded my database (Postgres and Postgis) as follows:

```
$ osm2pgsql -c -d gis --slim -C 50000  /var/lib/postgresql/data/germany-latest.osm.pbf
```

The closest related question I could find was [How to query all shops around a certain longitude/latitude using osm-postgis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968656/how-to-query-all-shops-around-a-certain-longitude-latitude-using-osm-postgis). I have taken the query, and plugged in a (lat, long) that I found in google maps for the city center of Munich (as the post was also related to city center Munich and I have the map for Germany). The result turns up empty.

```
gis=# SELECT name, shop FROM planet_osm_point WHERE ST_DWithin(way ,ST_SetSrid(ST_Point(48.137969, 11.573829), 900913), 100);
 name | shop 
------+------
(0 rows)
```

Also when looking into the planet_osm_nodes, which contains (lat, long) pairs directly, I end up with no results:

```
gis=# SELECT * FROM planet_osm_nodes WHERE ((lat BETWEEN 470000000 AND 490000000) AND (lon BETWEEN 100000000 AND 120000000)) LIMIT 10;
 id | lat | lon | tags 
----+-----+-----+------
(0 rows)
```

I verified the data is in my database:

```
gis=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM planet_osm_point;
  count  
---------
 9924531
(1 row)
```

and

```
gis=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM planet_osm_nodes;
   count   
-----------
 288597897
(1 row)
```

So ideally, my question would be 
Q: **How can I find the "max speed" and "highway" given a set (lat, lon)**
alternatively, my questions is:
Q: **How do I get the query from the other stack overflow post to work?**

My best guess is that I need to transform my (lat, lon) in some way, or that I simply have the wrong data for whatever reason.

Edit: added sample data as requested:

```
gis=# SELECT * FROM planet_osm_point LIMIT 1;
  osm_id   | access | addr:housename | addr:housenumber | addr:interpolation | admin_level | aerialway | aeroway | amenity | area | barrier | bicycle | brand | bridge | boundary | building | capital | construction | covered | culvert |
 cutting | denomination | disused | ele | embankment | foot | generator:source | harbour | highway  | historic | horse | intermittent | junction | landuse | layer | leisure | lock | man_made | military | motorcar | name | natural | off
ice | oneway | operator | place | poi | population | power | power_source | public_transport | railway | ref | religion | route | service | shop | sport | surface | toll | tourism | tower:type | tunnel | water | waterway | wetland | wi
dth | wood | z_order |                        way                         
-----------+--------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+---------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------+---------+--------------+---------+---------+
---------+--------------+---------+-----+------------+------+------------------+---------+----------+----------+-------+--------------+----------+---------+-------+---------+------+----------+----------+----------+------+---------+----
----+--------+----------+-------+-----+------------+-------+--------------+------------------+---------+-----+----------+-------+---------+------+-------+---------+------+---------+------------+--------+-------+----------+---------+---
----+------+---------+----------------------------------------------------
 304070863 |        |                |                  |                    |             |           |         |         |      |         |         |       |        |          |          |         |              |         |         |
         |              |         |     |            |      |                  |         | crossing |          |       |              |          |         |       |         |      |          |          |          |      |         |    
    |        |          |       |     |            |       |              |                  |         |     |          |       |         |      |       |         |      |         |            |        |       |          |         |   
|      |         | 010100002031BF0D0048E17A94F19F2941CDCCCCDCC60D5741
(1 row)
```

and

```
gis=# SELECT * FROM planet_osm_nodes LIMIT 1;
   id   |    lat    |   lon    | tags 
--------+-----------+----------+------
 234100 | 666501948 | 80442755 | 
(1 row)
```

Edit 2: There was a mention regarding "SRID", so I added example data from another table:

```
gis=# SELECT * FROM spatial_ref_sys LIMIT 1;
 srid | auth_name | auth_srid |                                                                                                                                                                    srtext                                  
                                                                                                                                  |                                           proj4text                                            
------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3819 | EPSG      |      3819 |  GEOGCS["HD1909",DATUM["Hungarian_Datum_1909",SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],TOWGS84[595.48,121.69,515.35,4.115,-2.9383,0.853,-3.408],AUTHORITY["EPSG","1024"]],PR
IMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3819"]] | +proj=longlat +ellps=bessel +towgs84=595.48,121.69,515.35,4.115,-2.9383,0.853,-3.408 +no_defs 
(1 row)
```

Comment: Pls edit your question and add some example data . I think it is question of SRID of your data sets. But without seeing data can't help much

Comment: Added a row per table as example data, if you are looking for anything specific please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Geometry in PostGIS has a different ordering of (lat long) first is going longitude then latitude. 
Also if you want to transform a point from one SRID to another use st_transfrom(), not ST_SetSrid.
ST_Transform relly transform your data from one coordinates system to another.

```
select st_astext(st_transform(ST_SetSrid(ST_Point(11.573829,48.137969), 4326),900913))
```

ST_SetSrid - just change SRID for the object.

```
select st_astext((ST_SetSrid(ST_Point(11.573829,48.137969),900913)
```

So, you have to change your SQL that way

```
SELECT name, shop 
  FROM planet_osm_point
 WHERE ST_DWithin(way,st_transform(ST_SetSrid(ST_Point(11.573829,48.137969), 4326),900913), 100);
```